# Add rewrite_rule not working

Tags: wordpress

I am making a master/detail pattern sort of page in my theme. 
When a person clicks a username, they will be taken to a page with that user's complete information. I did this by putting a link on the master page and then using `$_GET` to include said user's id in the url.
When i click the user name however, I am being redirected to index.php. I have tried `add_rewrite_rule()` but I'm still being redirected to index.In my functions.php I have the below code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'fwwp_rewrites_init' );
function fwwp_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'user-profile/([0-9]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=user-profile&id=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Then in my `user-profile.php` I have:

```
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'fwwp_query_vars' );
    function fwwp_query_vars( $query_vars ){
    $query_vars[] = 'id';
    return $query_vars;
}
```

I even tried `remove_filter('template_redirect','redirect_canonical');`, so that i could at least get a 404, but I'm still being redirected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you tried [flushing the rewrite rules](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/)?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the URLs that are causing the issue so we can check if the rule is setup correctly?

Comment: this is the example url `http://localhost/wiz/wordpress/user-profile/id=3`

Comment: your rule is match `user-profile/3`

Comment: its `user-profile/id=3`. Its my regex isn't it?

Comment: I'm trying to use this regex now: `user-profile/([a-z][.][0-9]+)/?$` but its not working. I'm not very familiar with regexes. How should i write it so it matches a string like `user-profile/id=3`